# On page unload strophe.js sends request twice! why?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I'm new to Xmpp server and strophe.js, I implement it into my website for messaging. There is a problem when I am send a message it works fine, but after sending a message if I reload the page immediately then I saw that that message, which I send before reload saved in Xmpp server twice, and when I retrieve message from server obviously it return duplicate message. It is so embarrassing.

Can any one tell me any solutions to stop twice requesting when page load?

I saw a post where one developer told that he face with same problem and contact to strophe team they suggest him to replace the line 2566 of strophe.js file with this code 
`if (req.sends == 0) {
                   sendFunc();
                }`

I have already done it but my problem is still there. :(

Thanks,

biswajitGhosh

Comment: Why would you reload the the page immediately? What does your "send message" function look like?

Comment: `var message = $msg({ unitno: unit__no, conversationdept:dept, conversationID:conversationID, to: frd_uName, from: usrName, type: 'groupchat', id: 'forward_message'  }).c('body').t('notification');`

`conn.send(message.tree());`

Above is our code for send message implementation, in our system we are developing an user can get multiple messages from different user  and also can send message to several users from same page. We are showing the status change of the message from active to close that's why user refresh the page to see status of all messages.

Comment: Are you using the muc plugin? Is frd_uName a room jid or a person? And what is the significance "closing" a message? What is the messaging app for?

Comment: This message app for chatting with more than one client at a time. So he/she need to reload the page to know if there was any new messages.

When he/she write a message for Client-A and reload the page immediately the Client-A got the message twice. Our client'll not accept this. So have you any solutions to solve this ?

Comment: I have same issue while receive the chat on my web chat window it come twice ,but but i refresh page then i comes from DB and it shows single.So off course its issue with JS file.I have separate iframe for multiple chats here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create multiple divs/windows, one for each chat. Strophe is meant to be asynchronous so you don't have to reload. Reloading defeats the purpose of strophe. Add a handler to your connection once you attach/connect.

```
connection.addHandler(onMsg, null, 'message');
```

In your message handler, you can then determine which conversation the message belongs to and append it to the appropriate div.

```
var onMsg = function (msg) {
 var elems = msg.getElementsByTagName('body');
  if (elems.length > 0) {
   var type = msg.getAttribute('type');
   var from = msg.getAttribute('from');
   if (type == "chat") {
    //new chat message
   }
  }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark!
Sorry for late response, I apply your code this is very helpful for me and my project, but still there is a problem. 
I am using archiving plugin of XMPP server so, if I (strophe) send it twice, it (XMPP archiving plugin) will save the message twice.

Comment: Why would you send it twice?

Comment: Just to clarify that with the current requirement it is necessary to reload the page. The problem is just after sending the message if the page is refreshed it is being sent twice. Same issue has been mentioned in this SO post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752475/strophe-sending-double-request-on-page-unload?rq=1 but after following the answer for this post it did not solve our issue. So our main question is why Strophe is sending the message twice on immediate page unload after sending a message and has there been any recent fix ?